# Proof that $ e^{-x} = x $ has only one solution

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that the equation $ e^{-x} = x $ has only one solution in $ \left(0, 1\right) $. Here is my proof but I am not sure whether it's correct or not.

Proof:

Define $ f(x) = e^{-x} - x $. If the equation above has more than one solution, then according to Rolle's Theorem, there exists a minimum or a maximum in $ \left(0, 1\right) $, because $ f(x) $ is continuous.

According to Fermat's Theorem, if $ f(x) $ has an extrema point, then there exists a $ c \in \left(0, 1\right) $  such that $ f'(c) = 0 $.

But if $ f'(x) = -e^{-x} - 1 = 0$.

$$ -e^{-x} = 1 $$
$$ e^{-x} = -1 $$
$$ -x = \ln(-1) $$

However, the  domain of $ \ln(x) $ is $ \left(0, +\infty \right)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, the equation has at most one solution.

$ f(x) $ is a continuous function because it's the sum of two continuous functions. Therefore, according to the Intermediate Value Theorem, if there exists a $ x_1 $ such that $ f(x_1) > 0 $ and there exists a $ x_2 $ such that $ f(x_2) < 0 $, then there exists an $ x $ such that $ f(x) = 0$.

$ f(0.1) = 0.8 $

$ f(0.9) = -0.49 $

Therefore there exists at least one solution to the equation.

Thus there exists exactly one solution to the equation.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: yes, your proof seems correct to me :)

Comment: I'm bothered by your line $-x=\ln(-1)$, because $\ln(-1)$ is undefined $-$ so it's not so much a _contradiction_, as a _meaningless statement_. I think it's cleaner just to say that since $e^{-x}$ is always positive, $e^{-x}=-1$ has no solutions.

Comment: In your final step, how do you know that $f(1) = .8$ and $f(.9) = -.49$? (And aren’t those statements actually false?)

Comment: A stylistic comment: you should use correct grammar when writing math; don’t just write down a list of equations with no punctuation.

Comment: @littleO Those are approximations. I just plugged the values in the calculator

Comment: How do you know the calculator was correct?

Comment: One shouldn’t make false statements in a proof. The statement $f(.1) = .8$ is false.

Comment: $x-e^{-x}$ is increasing, hence injective: $x-e^{-x}=0$ cannot have more than one solution.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x}-x \implies f'(x)=-e^{-x}-1<0$. So $f(x)$ is a decreasing function, hence $f(x)=0$ has at most one real root. Next since $f(-\infty)>0$ abd $f(\infty)<0$ by IVT $f(x)=0$ will have exactly one real root.

Further since $f(0)=1>0$ and $f(1)=e^{-1}-1<0$, the single real root lies in $(0,1).$